# Spring Integration Object To Map Transformer

Tags: spring-integration

I am using SI 4.0 and trying to use `object-to-map-transformer` as below

```
<integration:object-to-map-transformer input-channel="inputChannel" 
    output-channel="outChannel" >
</integration:object-to-map-transformer>
```

I am sending a object like Person class on the inputChannel. But the moment I fire my test it fails with following error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither jackson-databind.jar, 
    nor jackson-mapper-asl.jar aren't presented in the classpath. at
org.springframework.integration.support.json.JacksonJsonUtils.<clinit>(JacksonJsonUtils.java:41)
```

I dont understand why it needs jackson. I looked at SI code and can see it needs Jackson class but why is this need - when I simply need to map a simple object to Map?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code to convert `object to map` looks like:

```
Map<String,Object> result = this.jsonObjectMapper.fromJson(this.jsonObjectMapper.toJson(payload), Map.class);
```

Since the out of the box implementation for the `JsonObjectMapper` is Jackson, it requires that the last one should be presented in the classpath.

We decided to use JSON notation for the `Map` presentation, since any object in JSON has map-based structure.

If you have another algorithm to do the same, the contribution is welcome!

Or you can simply implement your own `Transformer` with that logic and use it from generic `<transformer>`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I will update if I can think through something.